# System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountExeception: Parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager ResManager
    = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(
        "derp",
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

byte[] cmBytes
    = System.Convert.FromBase64String((string)ResManager.GetObject("cFile"));

/*BinaryWriter bw1
      = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("test.exe", FileMode.Create));
  bw1.Write(cmBytes);
  bw1.Flush();
  bw1.Close();*/

Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(cmBytes);
MethodInfo mi = asm.EntryPoint;
object go = asm.CreateInstance(mi.Name);
mi.Invoke(go, null);
```

The error is pointing to `mi.Invoke(go, null)`, I am stumped here.

Comment: May be Invoke function is referenced by some delegate which has diffrent number of Arguments than the signature of deligate

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit? Your code snippet is inconvenient to read with the horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case an entry point takes parameters - as the exception suggests (probably a list of strings), so obviously you can't invoke it without parameters (`null` as second argument). Try:

```
mi.Invoke(go, new object[] { new string[0] } );
```

Note that this will of course work only for assemblies with an entry point accepting list of strings. Depending on types of the assemblies you want to run you may want to add some more logic to this. You could also have `static void Main()` in the assembly, so your version would've work.